# Claim about differentiability from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading over my notes and there is a claim that states:

if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $|f(x)| \le |x|^2$ on $|x| < \delta$, for some $\delta > 0$, x must be differentiable at x=0.

I am having trouble believing this to be true, and it is without any explanation or proof. Could someone please enlighten me? This is bothering me quite a bit.

Comment: hint: prove that the derivative is $0$

Answer (score 1):

A function $g\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there is a vector $D$ such that
$$
g(x)=g(x_0)+D\cdot(x-x_0)+R(x), \quad \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{R(x)}{|x|}=0.
$$
Apply this to $f$ at $x_0=0$ with $D=(0,\dots,0)$:
$$
f(x)=0+D\cdot x+f(x),\quad \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=0.
$$